# Apply Blend-Mode on transparent image

Tags: css, alphablending, background-blend-mode

using CSS, i'm trying to blend a background-image with a color.
The image is a PNG with translucent parts though.
How can I apply a blend-mode only to the actually visible parts, so if the PNG has a hole, the elements lying behind can be seen unobstructed there?

Codes like:

```
background-image: url("Scales/Scale1.png");
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
background-blend-mode: luminosity;
```

result in an opaque color blending with the image ontop. Fully translucent pixels of the image contain the background-color instead of being translucent on the result.

Anyone having an idea how to solve this?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Only with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

```
filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
```

and `sepia(NN%)` probably. No other options and only in browsers that support it.